# Get string length from user input

Tags: go

I want to get the string length, here my code:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("Text to send: ")
    text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    fmt.Print(strconv.Itoa(len(text)))

}
```

For input: `aaa`

The output is `5` but should be `3`.

I know I can just subtract -2 from the result but I want "cleaner" way

Comment: Try trimming whitespace. See the `strings` package for that.

Comment: Try `fmt.Printf("%q\n", text)` to find out what the "invisible" characters are. Also note that `fmt.Print` takes any type of argument, so there is no need to convert the result of `len` into a string, it's enough to use `fmt.Print(len(text))`. https://play.golang.com/p/Y526qFDbmbD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove whitespaces from your input:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
     reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
     fmt.Print("Text to send: ")
     text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
     newText := strings.TrimSpace(text)
     fmt.Print(strconv.Itoa(len(newText)))    
}
```

Comment: For input `a` it prints `2` but should print `1`

Comment: can you please fix the answer?

Comment: Trim space should remove all whitespaces